# Find the critical Points for this equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So for this equation, I already found the derivative and now to find the critical points, I have to set it equal to 0 and solve for x.

The equation is: $f'(x) = 2x\ln x + x = 0$

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I've never heard anyone refer to a critical point of an equation.  Functions and functionals have critical points.

Answer (score 3):

Factor out the $x$: $$x(2 \ln x + 1) = 0 \implies x = 0 \text{ or } \ln x = -\frac 12$$

Now, what must $x$ be for $\;\ln x = -\frac 12\;$?

Hint: raise each side to a power of $e$: $$\ln x = -\frac 12 \iff e^{\ln x} = e^{-1/2} \quad \iff  \quad x = e^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt e}$$

So our two solutions to the equation are $x = 0,$ and $\;x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt e}.$

Comment: Nice explanation and hint +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, $$0=2x\ln x+x=x(2\ln x+1),$$ so $x=0$ or $2\ln x+1=0.$ Can you take it from there, making sure to check that your solutions are in the function's domain?

Also, it's worth keeping in mind that critical points can occur where the original function is defined, but the derivative is not. For example, $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ has a critical point at $x=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Factor out an x term which does not give you a solution because of the natural log. Hovever, $lnx=-0.5$ gives an answer